# How do I perform multithreading in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a rather standard GWT form that performs the very basic function of grabbing data from a registration form and storing it in the database.

```
authenticationService.registerStudent(email, password, firstName, lastName, contact,
            country, countryCode, school, lecturerFirstName, lecturerLastName,
            lecturerEmail, language, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Boolean bool) {

        }
    });
```

On the server side, I have a servlet that stores the data into a database.

```
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements AuthenticationService {

@Override
public Boolean registerStudent(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName,
                               String contact, String country, String countryCode, String school,
                               String lecturerFirstName, String lecturerLastName, String lecturerEmail,
                               String language) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    ....

    }
}
```

I want to send send a confirmation email to the person asking him to confirm the account. The problem with implementing the email logic in the `registerStudent()` function is that it might take a while to communicate with the SMTP server which will cause unresponsiveness on the client-side.

How do I "delegate" the sending email functionality to another class/function while being able to return `true` from the `registerStudent()` function upon successful insertion to the database? I presume some form of multithreading is going to be needed but I am unsure how to go about doing it.

Comment: I agree with sanbhat's answer. Altough, specifically for this question about sending a registration email, I'd say that sending the e-mail synchronously (ie: lock the client and wait for the e-mail to be sent) isn't such a bad alternative because then you would be able to provide a feedback to the client in case something went wrong with sending the email, such as "overloaded service, please try again later"....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AuthenticationServiceImpl` is a GWT Servlet and here there is **no restriction** in the usage of any Java's library. You can create a `Runnable` and pass it to `Thread` and invoke `start()` so that it sends the mail  in parallel. The runnable's `run()` method should have the logic of sending email.

You can see more documentation and examples on multithreading [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: I think that's the right answer because the important thing is: You can do whatever you want to in the servlet. Then, depending on what framework you are using on the server side there might be thousands of possible implementations and design to send that e-mail :)

Answer (score 2):

Since on the server side you have full access to the Java class libraries, you can use threading to start a new thread that takes care of sending the email.

Something like this:

```
public class sendRegistrationEmail implements Runnable {
   @Override public void run() {
      ... here goes the code to send email ...
}
```

then you can start a new thread with:

```
Thread emailThread = new Thread( new sendRegistrationEmail() );
emailThread.start();
```